# Extracting the Address tag from HTML using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Can't seem to string the following HTML:

```
[<address class="styles_address__zrPvy"><svg class="styles_addressIcon__3Pu3L" height="42" viewbox="0 0 32 42" width="32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M14.381 41.153C2.462 23.873.25 22.1.25 15.75.25 7.051 7.301 0 16 0s15.75 7.051 15.75 15.75c0 6.35-2.212 8.124-14.131 25.403a1.97 1.97 0 01-3.238 0zM16 22.313a6.562 6.562 0 100-13.125 6.562 6.562 0 000 13.124z"></path></svg>Level 1 44 Market Street<!-- -->, <!-- -->Sydney</address>]
```

The "title" is working fine but the "address" is not extracting.

```
path = "C:\\Users\\mpeter\\Downloads\\lksd\\"

titleList = []

for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.html")):
    markup = (infile)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open(markup, "r").read(), 'lxml')
    title = soup.find_all("title")
    title = soup.title.string
    titleList.append(title)
    
streetAddressList = []

for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.html")):
    markup = (infile)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open(markup, "r").read(), 'lxml')
    address = soup.find_all("address", class_={"styles_address__zrPvy"})
    address = soup.address.string
    streetAddressList.append(address)
  
with open('output2.csv', 'w') as myfile:
   writer = csv.writer(myfile)
   writer.writerows((titleList, streetAddressList))
```

When I take out the address = soup.address.string it works but extracts the whole Element.

Comment: You could use `regex` to only find the adress. When you've already got the whole element in `adress`

Comment: @grumpyp, looking into it now. Any pointers on how it would be done I'm guessing 'address = re.compile (r"Something")'. Not sure what to put in something though.

Answer (score 0):

Using findall we can get all matched content. then need to iterate over the resultset to get the each content.

use this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
strs = '[<address class="styles_address__zrPvy"><svg class="styles_addressIcon__3Pu3L" height="42" viewbox="0 0 32 42" width="32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M14.381 41.153C2.462 23.873.25 22.1.25 15.75.25 7.051 7.301 0 16 0s15.75 7.051 15.75 15.75c0 6.35-2.212 8.124-14.131 25.403a1.97 1.97 0 01-3.238 0zM16 22.313a6.562 6.562 0 100-13.125 6.562 6.562 0 000 13.124z"></path></svg>Level 1 44 Market Street<!-- -->, <!-- -->Sydney</address>] [<address class="styles_address__zrPvy"><svg class="styles_addressIcon__3Pu3L" height="42" viewbox="0 0 32 42" width="32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M14.381 41.153C2.462 23.873.25 22.1.25 15.75.25 7.051 7.301 0 16 0s15.75 7.051 15.75 15.75c0 6.35-2.212 8.124-14.131 25.403a1.97 1.97 0 01-3.238 0zM16 22.313a6.562 6.562 0 100-13.125 6.562 6.562 0 000 13.124z"></path></svg>14, Bengaluru<!-- -->, <!-- -->India</address>]'
soup = BeautifulSoup(strs, 'lxml')
addresses = soup.find_all(class_={"styles_address__zrPvy"})
addr = []
df = pd.DataFrame()
for address in addresses:
    addr.append(address.text)
df['address'] = addr
df
```

Output:

```
   address
0   Level 1 44 Market Street, Sydney
1   14, Bengaluru, India
```

now the list of addresses is in Dataframe. you can write this dataframe into a csv using `df.to_csv()`

Comment: Hey, it isn't working as it is a 'soup.find_all'. The reason for this is because I am pulling it from multiple files. Any assistance is greatly appreciated

Comment: Updated the answer with findall()

Comment: Hi Subbu, sorry, though how do I implement it so it writes the list to a CSV? As you can see from my sample above, it has that as the end function. You're help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: updated the answer with creating a dataframe and writing into a csv file

Comment: Hi @Subbu VidyaSekar, sorry to be a pain but can you amend it so it's using the 'glob' function as it is being extracted from _local_ HTML files. The original code above is what I want it to come from. Thanks mate =)